# Ubuntu-Studio 14.04.3 LTS "Trusty Tahr" on an Acer Aspire V5 laptop and won't display anything through HDMI

Tags: nvidia, hdmi

```
jah@jah-Aspire-V5-571G:~$ xrandr
Screen 0: minimum 8 x 8, current 1366 x 768, maximum 32767 x 32767
LVDS1 connected 1366x768+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 345mm x 194mm
   1366x768       60.1*+
   1360x768       59.8     60.0  
   1024x768       60.0  
   800x600        60.3     56.2  
   640x480        59.9  
DP1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
HDMI1 connected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
   1920x1080i     50.0 +   60.1     60.0  
   1280x720       60.0     50.0     59.9  
   720x576        50.0  
   720x576i       50.1  
   720x480        60.0     59.9  
   720x480i       60.1     60.1  
   640x480        60.0     59.9  
VGA1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
VIRTUAL1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
VGA-1-2 connected
   1024x768       60.0  
   800x600        60.3     56.2  
   848x480        60.0  
   640x480        59.9  
  1024x768 (0x43)   65.0MHz
        h: width  1024 start 1048 end 1184 total 1344 skew    0 clock   48.4KHz
        v: height  768 start  771 end  777 total  806           clock   60.0Hz
  800x600 (0x44)   40.0MHz
        h: width   800 start  840 end  968 total 1056 skew    0 clock   37.9KHz
        v: height  600 start  601 end  605 total  628           clock   60.3Hz
  800x600 (0x45)   36.0MHz
        h: width   800 start  824 end  896 total 1024 skew    0 clock   35.2KHz
        v: height  600 start  601 end  603 total  625           clock   56.2Hz
```

It detects HDMI when I plug it in, but I can get nothing showing on my tv screen (Sony Bravia).

I suspect there may not be any solutions out there, as Ubuntu does seem to have alot of trouble with NIVIDA drivers and Sony Bravias.

Comment: What nvidia card model do you have?

Comment: Thank you very much,   sorry  it is a Nvidia Optimus, I eventually managed a cold start with hdmi and its working! I was also having trouble with not being able to turn my system off, this time it did a proper restart.

Comment: I updated the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have the Nvidia Geforce GT 750M card, run the following commands and reboot. If you don't have this card, do not run these commands, leave me a comment and provide the proper card instead.

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install nvidia-361
```

Reboot.

This will install the proprietary drivers for your nvidia card.

If you are not sure, search for "additional drivers" in your dash and then select the tested "proprietary" driver for your card. I believe it is nvidia-361 then reboot. This will install the proprietary drivers for your card. Performance has shown to be much better with the proprietary driver.

Comment: @HermioneG Yes, but this  model should be something like Nvidia Geforce GT 750M.

Comment: @HermioneG Follow the instructions above or run the command: `ubuntu-drivers devices`